# find the order of the cyclic subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_{84}$ generated by 12

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

How do you determine the order a cyclic subgroup?

Specifically when dealing with a certain number like $12$?

I know that the order of a subgroup is simply put, the number of distinct elements in the subgroup.

My confusion is what does it mean to generate elements by $12$?

Comment: What does $\text{z}_84$ mean?

Comment: The elements of the subgroup are just elements of the form $\sum_{i=0}^k \pm 12$. So, you have $\{...,-12,0,12,24,36,48,60,72,84,...\}$ but $84\equiv 0$ mod 84, so the distinct elements are $\{0,12,24,36,48,60,72\}$ which has order 84/12=7.

Comment: @user722227 You should make that an answer.

Comment: keep adding $12$ until you get to $84$

Comment: Well that was ridiculously easy

Answer (score 2):

How many times do you need to sum $12$ with itself to get $0 \pmod {84}$? That's the order of $12$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{84}$. Why $0$? Because that's the unit of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_n$, whatever $n$.